# Apple XDR Display connected to PC; Why do some Thunderbolt 3 cables work while others don't?

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I have a 2019 era MacBook Pro that's connected to an Apple XDR monitor via a Thunderbolt 3 cable. This works great.

**What I'd like to do is occasionally hook up a Dell Precision 7760 laptop to this Apple XDR monitor**. The Dell has two Thunderbolt 4, USB 3.2 ports:
[image]

My thought was to use the Thunderbolt 3 Pro cable that came with the Apple XDR monitor, and plug it into the Dell. This didn't work. The Dell just beeped but no image ever appeared on the monitor.

"Ok," I thought, "I guess the XDR monitor and Dell laptop are just fundamentally incompatible."

Then, just to see what would happen, I tried connecting the Dell to the XDR using a USB-C 3.2 Gen 2 cable that came with a high speed SSD that I purchased a few days ago. To my amazement, it actually worked. The Dell started broadcasting a clear picture to the XDR.

**Why did this work with the cheap cable that came with my SSD but failed with the expensive Thunderbolt 3 Pro cable that came with the XDR monitor?** The latter isn't defective. Recall it works just fine with the MacBook Pro. Since the XDR is Thunderbolt 3 and the Dell is Thunderbolt 4 and the cable is Thunderbolt 3, shouldn't this "just work" at a Thunderbolt 3 level?

What I'm ultimately getting at is this: I can't use the cheap SSD cable for monitor connectivity long-term because it's just too short. I need to buy a longer cable that connects the Dell to the XDR but it appears not all Thunderbolt cables are created equal. What do I look for when buying the cable?

PS: This isn't a "what should I do" question. I'm not asking for a product recommendation. I'm just trying to understand why one Thunderbolt 3 cable fails while another succeeds when connecting the Apple XDR to a Dell, and more generally what characteristics I should be on the lookout for when buying Thunderbolt 3/4 cables for use with the Apple XDR monitor.

Thanks

Comment: So unless you give the technical specs of both cables you have any answer will be a guess. And without being able to test the monitor that did not work any answer may stll be a guess. Perhaps the connector on the Dell is at one extreme of the fitting tolerances and the cheap cable matches it well while the other cable does not.